# How to use Toad for MySQL to change Magento 2 auto_increment value?

Tags: mysql, magento, toad

I want to increase the order number value (eg, from 100000001 to 100050000) so that it counts upwards from the new value I set.

In phpmyadmin, you go to 'operations' and simply amend the value in the auto_increment field.

In Toad, all I see is an un-editable field under the information tab.

How do I go about editing auto_increment values in toad?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, worked it out..

You have to go to the scripts tab, then click the 'open in scripts editior icon', then delete any existing table scripts in there and put ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 50000; and click the 'execute scripts' icon.